# Spark BigQuery connector set temporaryGcsBucket credentials per DataFrameWriter

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

Currently we are using following code to write spark dataframe to BigQuery:

```
  outDF.write
    .format("bigquery")
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "bq_temporary_folder")
    .option("parentProject", "user_project")
    .option("table", "user.destination_table")
    .option("credentials", <base 64 encoded bq creds>)
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save()
```

this only allow the Bq query credentials per DataFrameWriter, not for the tmp gcs bucket,
we have to specify the global hadoop settings for that purpose, otherwise, we will get the access denied error when BigQuery connector trying to write a staging file to the tmp gcs buckect.
my question is that if it is possible for the spark bigquery connector to set the gcs creds too, we are using a shared Databricks env, and we do not want to set a global gcs bucket creds in the hadoop settings, which cause conflicts and not secure too.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work:

```
path_to_cred_file = get_path_to_cred_file('dev')
spark.write.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", path_to_cred_file)
```

and just implement `get_path_to_cred_file()` to create the path using various parameters for a given environment/bucket/...

As [described here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#how-do-i-authenticate-outside-gce--dataproc).